# How do I decide whether to represent rating attributes as columns in a table or entries?

Tags: database-design

I am writing a small program for a management system in my office to keep track of the work of certain parties/offices and I know that they will be rated on four attributes, let's call them A, B, C, D.

Though not important in the scale of this project this came as a thought problem to me. How would I decide between the following two solutions?

First Solution:(This is what I am thinking of doing)
Since I know the number of the attributes and all of them will always be filled for every office every week I was thinking I can just create a table of ratings with columns the office id, the date/id of inspection and four columns for each attribute rated on.

Second Solution:
Create the table for ratings with the office id and inspection/date id and add two columns one for the rating type and another the rating value.
In addition to that I will have a table with a list of rating types (with codes as a primary key) and I was thinking of a columns with a rating scale which would lead to another table called ratingScales where there would be a list of the ratings scales (one column) and the possible values (second column). I feel it is overcomplicating things but remember this is a though that came to me in case of a larger scale project not what i am doing. I was thinking that this way I could set each rating attribute different scales like for instance one could have values yes/no, another 1-4, another low, medium, high. So I could use bound values in the rating values in the original table (I would use the foreign key of the rating attribute to get the scale of that attribute and then a list of the possible values)...

So I was thinking how would one go to decide. The second solution seems make it easier if you don't want to add for every rating attribute or add inthe future but again i don't thinkg it would be too much trouble to add a column... except if the table would be too huge...

Is there some kind of thinking that could be taken into account or something else?

Comment: Option 2 is the way to go for various reasons

Comment: Some general rules of thumb in database design are: 1) use type information for table and column names, and data goes in the cells, and 2) dissimilar things go horizontal (columns) and similar things go vertical (rows). (However, always remember and never forget, there are exceptions to every rule.)

Comment: i'd go with the first. the second option sounds like eav which is a pain in the ass if you have to write queries against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is a denormalized solution, the second is normalized.  Each has its value.

For instance, if you had a weather station that had instruments keeping track of temperature, humidity, wind speed, wind direction, and air pressure each hour at various locations, then the first solution is quite reasonable.  Changing the metrics is a big thing -- you have to change equipment in the real world at multiple locations.  It is quite likely that all the measurements are available, or none at all.  In fact, the values "belong together" as a description of the weather at each location.

At the other extreme, you might have different groups going to an office to rate different things -- a health inspector, a financial inspector, and so on.  These are not related, so the base data does not belong in the same row.

In general, when faced with a problem like this, you want to opt for flexibility.  The second solution offers flexibility in two important ways:

- You can add new ratings without much trouble.
- You can add new attributes for the ratings -- such as a specific date/time or who made the rating -- more easily.

The general answer is to go with the more normalized form.  However, there may be exceptions based on the details of the situation.

Comment: Thank you. I do agree with you but it's always nice to confirm it with a 3rd person. Like you said, in my case it's a small scale and very unlikely to change so for the sake of speed and ease I will go with the denormalized solution but I wanted to see what other people thought for larger scales and why... Your example is a very clear. Thank you